# Save multiple dataframes with different headers into one file using Pyspark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I want to save 3 different DataFrames into one file ( such as csv or txt)

*df_1*

| id | FileDate | FileTime | FileType | File Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230713 | 17:12:23 | ENS | Update |

*df_2*

| id | name | postal | provider |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jame | 12345 | ATT |
| 2 | Anne | 12145 | Verizon |
| 3 | John | 32145 | ATT |
| 4 | David | 14215 | Verizon |

*df_3*

| RecordType | TotalRecords |
| --- | --- |
| RC | 200 |

I want the file should look like this. The first line will be `df1`, the middle be `df2` and the last line be `df3`

```
1|20230713|17:12:23|ENS|Update
1|Jame|12345|ATT     
2|Anne|12145|Verizon 
3|John|32145|ATT     
4|David|14215|Verizon 
RC|200
```

So, I am trying this but did not succeed.

```
df1.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("sep","|").option("header", "false").save(output_path)
df2.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("sep","|").option("header", "false").save(output_path)
df3.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("sep","|").option("header", "false").save(output_path)
```

I might be missing something here. How can I handle this?

Comment: Do you have access to the original CSVs? This would be pretty easy with the standard csv module reading the CSVs and pretty much directly concatenating them.

Comment: those tables are from delta lake and I do not know how to do that in pyspark

Comment: Can you try cross join and then generate the row number After that sort it by row number .

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to save multiple data frames into one pipe delimited file

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark
from functools import reduce


def create_text_file(list_df, path, file_name):
    ### This function save multiple dataframes with different headers into one pipe delimited file (.txt file)

    # Concatenate the multi columns into one column, then separate the different column values with `|` and create a list of dataframes
    list_single_column_df = [df.select(F.concat_ws("|", *df.columns).alias("data")) for df in list_df]

    # Union a list of dataframes
    final_df = reduce(pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.unionByName, list_single_column_df)

    # Save dataframe into text 
     final_df.coalesce(1).write.format("text").mode("append").save(path)


list_df = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
create_text_file(list_df, path, file_name)
```

The expected output should be like this

```bash
1|20230713|17:12:23|ENS|Update
1|Jame|12345|ATT     
2|Anne|12145|Verizon 
3|John|32145|ATT     
4|David|14215|Verizon 
RC|200
```